# What’s the best way to add a marker/pin over an image?

Tags: java, android, imageview, marker

I already searched on this matter and the answers weren’t very clear what’s the best way to achieve this **without using Bitmap**.

I want to add various markers/pins over an image, like for example an ImageView without using a Bitmap.

The objective is to have a big image (e.g. an indoor map) that I can zoom/pan and I need to hardcode all this markers over it like locations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yourImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here `R.id.yourImageView` is your image view with the map. `R.id.overlay` is a ViewGroup (FrameLayout seems to be the simplest but you can use any type you want) in which programatically you can add and position your markers as View objects. Markers could also be another ImageViews with loaded images.

The deal with the FrameLayout is that all its children lay on top of each other so this way you can use `R.id.overlay` as additional layer over `R.id.yourImageView`.

If you want to have zoom/pan you should attach `TouchListener` and somehow manipulate both layers simultaneously but this is another topic.

Comment: don't have much experience with FrameLayout but for what I tried how can I be precise in the position of the marker if I only have the positions in layout:gravity (top, bottom, left, right)? Thanks in advance

Comment: When you add children in the Frame Layout they are actually positioned all over each other (very similar to layers). This is not the same as in Linear Layout or Relative Layout where the children are arrange side by side.

Comment: For positioning the children inside the Frame Layout you can use their paddings (or margins) to add left and top offsets (right and bottom I think would not be very practical in this case). To control their size of course you can use layout_width and layout_height.